# Simple jQuery Personality Quiz

Tags: javascript, jquery

Attempting to create a simplfied version of the following quiz: [Example](http://codepen.io/jannypie/pen/DcHdo?editors=101)

```
enter code here
```

For my quiz, however, regardless of the answer, I don't want scores calculated as I just want to step through the quiz all the way through to a single result. Note: this is just for demo purposes, which is why the questions aren't weighted and the result will always be the same.

Taking what was done in the codepen example, I tried to make it so when the user clicks an input it will step to the next question (by adding class 'current') until the finally reach the result section.

[What I have so far](http://jsfiddle.net/9zg7xk64/3/). Help is appreciated.

```
<div class="quiz-step step1 current">
        <h2 class="question-title">In your mind, what's most important?</h2>
        <ul class="no-bullet answers">
          <li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="" class="quiz-answer"><label>Ability to express oneself</label> </li>
          <li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="" class="quiz-answer"><label>Ability to look at the big picture</label> </li>
          <li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="" class="quiz-answer"><label>Drive and determination</label> </li>
          <li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="" class="quiz-answer"><label>Understand logic and science</label> </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="quiz-step step2">
        <h2 class="question-title">What do you do best?</h2>
        <ul class="no-bullet answers">
          <li><input type="radio" name="q2" value="" class="quiz-answer"><label>Deal with stress</label> </li>
          <li><input type="radio" name="q2" value="" class="quiz-answer"><label>Effective time management</label> </li>
          <li><input type="radio" name="q2" value="" class="quiz-answer"><label>Use good judgment</label> </li>
          <li><input type="radio" name="q2" value="" class="quiz-answer"><label>Master interpersonal skills</label> </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="quiz-step step3">
        <h2 class="question-title">What is the key to being a successful marketer?</h2>
        <ul class="no-bullet answers">
          <li><input type="radio" name="q3" value="" class="quiz-answer"><label>Knowledge of data and statistics</label> </li>
          <li><input type="radio" name="q3" value="" class="quiz-answer"><label>Logical thinking and problem solving</label> </li>
          <li><input type="radio" name="q3" value="" class="quiz-answer"><label>People person &ndash; interaction</label> </li>
          <li><input type="radio" name="q3" value="" class="quiz-answer"><label>Advising, Analying, Evaluating</label> </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div id="results" class="quiz-step">
        <h2>result</h2>
      </div>
```

JS

```
    // global vars
    var quizSteps = $('.quiz-step');

    quizSteps.each(function() {
    var currentStep = $(this),
        ansOpts = currentStep.children('.quiz-answer');

    // for each step, add click listener
    // apply current active class
    ansOpts.each(function () {
        var eachOpt = $(this);
        eachOpt[0].addEventListener('click', check, false);
        function check() {
            var $this = $(this);
            // check to see if an answer was previously selected
            if (currentStep.children('.active').length > 0) {
                var wasActive = currentStep.children('.active');
                currentStep.children('.active').removeClass('active');
                $this.addClass('active');
            } else {
                $this.addClass('active');
                updateStep(currentStep);
            }
        }
    });
    });

// show current step/hide other steps
function updateStep(currentStep) {
    if(currentStep.hasClass('current')){
       currentStep.removeClass('current');
       currentStep.next().addClass('current');
    }
}
```

The Issue: when I select a radio option .. nothing is happening. It doesn't go to the next 'step' and display that step's question.

Comment: Bring your code here, and also what issues are you running into?

Comment: @zero298 -- added my code + issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the following line:

```
ansOpts = currentStep.children('.quiz-answer');
```

You want to use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) instead of [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) because the radio button elements are not direct children of the step element (that is, the element with the "quiz-step" class).

You could also get rid of one of the calls to `.each()`. I would also recommend using the jQuery `.click()` method to attach the event handler. See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2wsw6ak8/).